# EDSDK take picture without noise

Tags: c++, edsdk

I am an EDSDK newbie and I am using EDSDK v2.13 with my EOS 50D camera. 
I want to take a picture without noise or at least reduce the noise and without using the flash.

Is that possible? (with `EdsSetPropertyData` for example).

Comment: @dciriello please avoid abusing code markup for every single thing. Names of things are not code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really an EDSDK but more of a photography related question.
To have a low noise level you should use low ISO values. But the lower the ISO the darker the image, so you'll have to compensate that with Tv and Av.
Anyway, to set the ISO value with the SDK you should call `EdsSetPropertyData` as you suggested with the Propery ID `kEdsPropID_ISOSpeed`

Kind regards